# Debugging OnFileActivated in Windows 8

Tags: debugging, windows-8

I've associated my Windows 8 App with a file type. However when I open that file my app starts to open and then crashes.

I can't figure out a way to do this while the debugger is attached.

I assume there is something wrong with my OnFileActiavted method so I've resorted to changing random bits of code in that method. This isn't working, so I'm wondering how I should debug this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this work? You can debug without launching the app immediately. You can also debug other people's apps.

[image]

Comment: That is fantastic. There's an option in there not to launch straight away, but to kick in when loaded next. So that works beautifully with loading files.

Comment: Thanks for finding this - it helped me debug a file association launching bug.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach:

```
Debugger.Launch();
```

When your app starts and execution reaches this line, your app will be stopped and VS will ask if you want to attach a debugger.