# On launch file debugging

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I need to load a file when my app is launched by double clicking on an file associated with it. I use FileActivatedEventArgs in OnStartAsync method to achieve this. So far so good but what I'me unable to do is debug this on launch file loading since I don't know how to specify specific "onlaunch file" in VS2017.

I tried to set the path a app parameters but it doesnt work. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377578/debugging-onfileactivated-in-windows-8) helpful? This debugging trick should applicable to UWP too.

Comment: There should also be an option, something like `Debug > Other debug targets` where you can debug things like app prelaunch and so on and there's something that could be used for your need. Don't have access to VS at the moment so couldn't guide you more specifically.

Comment: Thanks guys. This works. However It feels a little bit clumsy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to debug any installed app package, like kennyzx and Marian Dolinský's suggestion, Debug > Other Debug Targets > Debug Installed App Package would be a nice solution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-installed-app-package

But if you just want to debug other app during you debug another one, maybe you could start debugging multiple processes in a Visual Studio solution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-multiple-processes